# Use of Sort with custom functions

Tags: sorting

As mentionned in the topic title, I try to apply my own sorting functions to a set of elements via the Sort command. I make here a quick presentation of the subject before.

**1) Method**

---

*We will remain in 2D throughout the description of the problem*

**1-1) Treatment of the component**

We consider a component of a vector as a real number.
To sort two real, it is necessary to compare them.
The particularity of the sort that I want to apply is that the comparison depend of a specific criterion `c` which can take two values (`"max"` and `"min"`).

In this case, to qualify the order relation between the two numbers, we won't say that :
- `something1` is superior/inferior to `something2` but,
- `something1` dominate/don't dominate `something2`.

You can either :
- Wanting to maximize the value of the component. `c = "max"`
- Wanting to minimize the value of the component. `c = "min"`

Example :

With :

Group n°1 : `a1 = 5` and `a2 = 3`
Group n°2 : `a3 = -2` and `a4 = -3`

- If `c = "max"`
  We have `a1 > a2`, so `a1` dominates `a2`.
  We have `a3 > a4`, so `a1` dominates `a2`.
- If `c = "min"`
  We always have `a1 > a2`, but now `a2` dominates `a1`.
  We always have `a3 > a4`, but now `a1` dominates `a2`.

Remarks :
- We can not decide in case of equality, so no number dominates another.
- The criterion `c` allows you to change the sort direction.

**1-2) Treatment of the vector**

The functions that I want to use, are based on the principle of dominance (translated from french), and its variations.

*Principle 1* :
We say that a vector `J` dominates a vector `K` if :
- `J` is at least as good as `K` in all component.
- `J` is strictly better than `K` in at least one component.

Examples :

Take two vector such as :

`v1 = {2, 5}`;
`v2 = {1, 6}`;

We have several possibilities to compare this two vector according to the value of the criterion `c` for each of these components.

- `v1[[1]] > v2[[1]]`
- `v1[[2]] < v2[[2]]`

Case 1 : `{"max","max"}`
We can't say if a vector dominate an other.

Case 2 : `{"max","min"}`
`v1` dominate `v2`.

Case 3 : `{"min","max"}`
`v2` dominate `v1`.

Case 4 : `{"min","min"}`
We can't say if a vector dominate an other.

So we can see here, that the sort of this two vector depend directly of the value of `c`.

**2) My code**

---

```
CompO[w_, x_, y_] :=
  Block[
       {Res},
        Res = If[
                 x == y,
                 {0},
                 If[w == "max", Ordering[{x, y}, -1], Ordering[{x, y}, 1]]]
       ];

BoolCompVDS[w__, x__, y__] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, step3, Res},
         step1 = MapThread[CompO, {w, x, y}];
         step2 = DeleteCases[Union@step1, 0, Infinity];
         step3 =
               If[
                  Count[step2, _Integer, Infinity] == 1,
                  Flatten@step2,
                 {0}
                 ];
          Res = If[step3 == {1}, True, False]
        ];
```

To understand :

We need to compare two vector :

```
v1 = {2, 5};
v2 = {1, 6};
```

The rule (for this example) are the following :
- We want to maximize the first component.
- We want to minimize the second component.

According to the principle 1 :

- `v1[[1]] > v2[[1]] so v1[[1]] dominate v2[[1]]` (we want to maximize)
- `v1[[2]] < v2[[2]] so v1[[2]] dominate v2[[2]]` (we want to minimize)

So `v1` dominate `v2` and :

```
BoolCompVDS[{"max","min"}, v1, v2]
```

give "True"

**3) Problem**

---

Thanks to the post of Mr. Wizards, my original question can be formulated like this :
Why the use of `Sort` with my personal function does not produce a strict order as may be the case with the use of the Norm function (for example) ?

As seen in the post of Mr Wizards, the Sort command is designed to work with strict order relations.
I would write an answer for an update on sorting with function based on dominance relations soon.

Comment: Please explain what do you exactly mean by "If the sort function BoolCompVDL Work, this is not the case with the functions BoolCompVDS and BoolCompVDM." (in which way/s they don't "work")

Comment: Agree *"that's a lot of information to integrate",* a more minimalistic question would be easier to answer.

Comment: You are giving too much irrelevant information. This is a serious mental load on all those who would try to answer. My first reaction is to ignore the question, and I am sure I am not alone. Look at some of the reasonably voted questions for examples of how to formulate a question well, and construct a *minimal* example, if you want to increase the chances for good answers.

Comment: Could you specify a general rule, how two vectors `{a, b}` and `{c, d}` should be ordered? I find part 2 of your question incredibly hard to comprehend. As I *think* I have gathered, the ordering `{{a, b}, {c, d}}` is correct if `a < c` and `b > d`, but for the example functions `#^2` and `#^3` this is never simultaneously realized.

Comment: Why is `BoolCompVDS` defined with three parameters of variable length i.e. `BoolCompVDS[w__, x__, y__]` and what do you expect this to do?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. The use of three parameters of variable length is to treat list of vector where the vector have dimensions higher than 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Establishing the question

Working through this post was confusing but I think I at least understand your question now.

First let me see if I can reduce your code quite a lot. :-)  I believe your `BoolCompVDS` can be replaced with merely this:

```
fn1[c_][v1_, v2_] := Min[#] >= 0 && Max[#] > 0 &[(v1 - v2) c]
```

The `c` parameter takes a list of `1` or `-1` representing `"max"` or `"min"` respectively.

There is equivalence:

```
rnd = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {100, 2, 2}];

Equal[
 BoolCompVDS[{"max", "max"}, #1, #2] & @@@ rnd,
 fn1[{1, 1}] @@@ rnd
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now **the question** is why the final output of this is not all `True`:

```
{{-2, -2}, {1, -4}, {1, 0}, {-1, -4}, {-3, 1}};
Sort[%, fn1[{1, 1}]]
Partition[%, 2, 1]
fn1[{1, 1}] @@@ %
```

> ```
> {{-3, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -4}, {-1, -4}, {-2, -2}}
>
> {{{-3, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, -4}}, {{1, -4}, {-1, -4}}, {{-1, -4}, {-2, -2}}}
>
> {False, True, True, False}
> ```

Is my understanding correct?

#### Examining the situation

I believe `Sort` operates assuming that the ordering function produces a strict order, meaning among other things that **a < b** and **b < c** implies **a < c**, and I believe your ordering function does not conform to this requirement.  Here is a simpler example of the issue:

```
fn = Mod[#, 2] < Mod[#2, 3] &;

Sort[Range @ 10, fn]

fn @@@ Partition[%, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {9, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 8, 10}
>
> {False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True}
> ```

I recall that there are ways to work with this kind of ordering though I cannot recall the details.  I think in any case the problem requires additional specification.  Some references that may help with that:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: `Min[#] >= 0 && Max[#] > 0 &` - if the smallest of two quantities is positive, no need to test if the larger quantity is also positive, no?

Comment: @J.M.  The minimum needs to be zero-or-greater, while the maximum must be strictly greater-than-zero.  This is by my understanding of the OP's *Principle 1* and it appears to agree with his own function.  I suppose another way to write this would be `NonNegative @ Min[#] && Max[#] != 0`.

Comment: What I had in mind was something like `Min[#] > 0 || Min[#] < Max[#]`, so that it short-circuits as soon as it is known that the minimum is positive.

Comment: @J.M. That didn't occur to me. :-)

Comment: @J.M. Wait, that's not the same either, as both values could be negative and pass that test.  Anyway, I think what I've got is clear enough, and it's not the focus of this question anyway, so if it ain't broke...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.  Based on your results, you understood everything.

Comment: @Doedalos I gave a quick overview of what I think the problem is, but I was not rigorous in my examination.  I ask that you take a look at it and the references I included, and if you feel my example does not demonstrate the same issue let me know why.

Comment: I had not paid attention to the difference between the concept of classical order and the strict notion of order until now. I will correct my initial post and suggest an answer about sorting with the principle of "domination" soon.

Answer (score 1):

I make here a rapid conclusion on the various sorting methods that I want to study.

The different elements to understand the problem and presented in the first post still valid.

Here you can see the various principles that I wanted to implement and the associated code.

**Principle**

---

- Principle 1 :
  We say that a vector `J` dominates a vector `K` if :
  -`J` is at least as good as `K` in all component.
  -`J` is strictly better than `K` in at least one component.
- Principle 2 :
  We say that a vector `J` dominates a vector `K` if :
  -If the value of the worst component of `J` is smaller than the worst component of `K`.
- Principle 3 :
  We say that a vector `J` dominates a vector `K` if :
  -There is an index value q such as all the components between 0 and q (included) are equal.
  -The component of `J` at the position (q + 1) dominates the component of K on the same position.

Here you can see the corresponding code :

```
CompO[w_, x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {Res},
        Res = If[
                 x == y,
                 {0},
                 If[w == "max", Ordering[{x, y}, -1], Ordering[{x, y},1]]
                ]
       ];


BoolCompVDS[w__, x__, y__] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, step3, Res},
         step1 = MapThread[CompO, {w, x, y}];
         step2 = DeleteCases[Union@step1, 0, Infinity];
         step3 =
               If[
                  Count[step2, _Integer, Infinity] == 1,
                  Flatten@step2,
                  {0}
                 ];
               Res = If[step3 == {1}, True, False]
        ];


BoolCompVDM[w__, x__, y__] :=
  Block[
        {step0, step1, step2, step3, step4, Res},
         step0 = {x, y};
         step1 = MapThread[CompO, {w, x, y}];
         step2 = (Flatten@step1) /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1};
         step3 = Ordering[Abs@Table[step0[[i, step2[[i]]]], {i, 1, 2, 1}], -1];
         step4 = (step2[[step3]]) /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1};
         Res = If[step4 == {1}, True, False]
       ];


BoolCompVDL[w__, x__, y__] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, step3, Res},
         step1 = Flatten@MapThread[CompO, {w, x, y}];
         step2 = FirstPosition[step1, 1 | 2, {0}];
         step3 = If[step2[[1]] != 0, step1[[step2]], {0}];
         Res = If[step3 == {1}, True, False]
        ];

SortVDS[x_, y_] := Sort[x, BoolCompVDS[y, #1, #2] &];
SortVDM[x_, y_] := Sort[x, BoolCompVDM[y, #1, #2] &];
SortVDL[x_, y_] := Sort[x, BoolCompVDL[y, #1, #2] &];
```

To compare the results of different sort :

```
data = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {10, 2}];

SortVDS[data, {"max", "max"}]
SortVDM[data, {"max", "max"}]
SortVDL[data, {"max", "max"}]
```

We obtain :

Random list >> `{{2, -5}, {-6, 5}, {6, 9}, {-6, -4}, {4, -6}}`

Sort n°1  >> `{{6, 9}, {4, -6}, {-6, 5}, {-6, -4}, {2, -5}}`
Sort n°2  >> `{{6, 9}, {-6, -4}, {-6, 5}, {2, -5}, {4, -6}}`
Sort n°3  >> `{{6, 9}, {4, -6}, {2, -5}, {-6, 5}, {-6, -4}}`

As mentioned by Mr.Wizards, only the principle 3 allows a total ordering.
This does not mean that the other sort are uninteresting.